# Exception with NSmutableArray of NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to do a list of lists... but when I use [listaCidades count] ...i'm getting throwing exception (sorry for long question but I mean that all this method is relevant for the question)

```
 -(void) preencherCidades  {
for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < [listaEstados count]; iCnt++) {
    NSString *estado = [listaEstados objectAtIndex:iCnt];
    NSArray *listaNomeCidades = nil;
    NSMutableArray *_listaCidades = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:estado ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    listaNomeCidades = [[file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]retain];

    for (int iCnt2 = 0; iCnt2 < [listaNomeCidades count]; iCnt2++) {
        NSArray *listaNomesPrefeitos = nil;
        NSArray *listaPartidosPrefeitos = nil;
        NSArray *listaVereadores = nil;

        NSString *pathNomePrefeitos = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"prefeito-nome-%@",[listaNomeCidades objectAtIndex:iCnt2]] ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *fileNomePrefeitos = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathNomePrefeitos encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        listaNomesPrefeitos = [[fileNomePrefeitos componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]retain];

        NSString *pathPartidoPrefeitos = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"prefeito-partido-%@",[listaNomeCidades objectAtIndex:iCnt2]] ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *filePartidoPrefeitos = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathPartidoPrefeitos encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        listaPartidosPrefeitos = [[filePartidoPrefeitos componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]retain];

        NSString *pathVereadores = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vereadores-%@",[listaNomeCidades objectAtIndex:iCnt2]] ofType:@"txt"];

        NSString *fileVereadores = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathVereadores encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        listaVereadores = [[fileVereadores componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]retain];
        Prefeito *prefeito = nil;
        if([listaNomesPrefeitos count] > 0 && [listaPartidosPrefeitos count]>0)
            prefeito = [[Prefeito alloc]initWithNome:[listaNomesPrefeitos objectAtIndex:0] partido:[listaPartidosPrefeitos objectAtIndex:0] id:iCnt2];
        Cidade *cidade = [[Cidade alloc]initWithNome:[listaNomeCidades objectAtIndex:iCnt2] prefeito:prefeito listaVereadores:listaVereadores id:iCnt2];

        [_listaCidades addObject:cidade];

    }
    [listaCidades addObject:_listaCidades];

}
}
```

Comment: Do you alloc/init listCidades anywhere? I see that you do for _listaCidades.

Comment: can u tell us what exception you are getting

Comment: @Joel yes, I did alloc and init in viewWillAppear `listaCidades = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

Comment: @SunilPandey "unrecongnized selector sent to instance ..."

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to see which line the unrecognized selector is on?

Comment: @monkybonk05 yes... the error is in: `- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSMutableArray *listaCidades2 = (NSMutableArray *)[listaCidades objectAtIndex:indiceEstado];
            return [listaCidades2 count];
   
}`  I have tried to use breakpoints and the listaCidades2 has 2 objects...

Comment: can you post your exception logs here. also NSLog once for listaCidades.

Comment: Can you tell the stack trace of the exception. It would be very easy to catch the error where ad what exception with that.

Comment: @SunilPandey **[Cidade isEqualToString:]:unrecognized selector to instance 0x1cec00**

Comment: I think you are returning Cidade object in picker view delegate method – pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent: .  You should return a string.

Comment: @nkongara thx! I solved this with  `NSMutableArray *listaCidades2 = (NSMutableArray *)[listaCidades objectAtIndex:indiceEstado];
        Cidade *cidade = (Cidade *)[listaCidades2 objectAtIndex:row];
        return cidade.nome;`

Comment: @nkongara pls, write your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your answer [Cidade isEqualToString:]:unrecognized selector to instance 0x1cec00.  I came to know that that is the only point where string is expected but you are returning Object.
Its good that you solve the issue.  Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with

```
NSMutableArray *listaCidades2 = (NSMutableArray *)[listaCidades objectAtIndex:indiceEstado];  
Cidade *cidade = (Cidade *)[listaCidades2 objectAtIndex:row];
 return cidade.nome;
```

instead of:

```
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSMutableArray *listaCidades2 = (NSMutableArray *)[listaCidades objectAtIndex:indiceEstado]; 
return [listaCidades2 objectAtIndex:row];
 }
```